# SP 2013 search: SiteTitle managed property not populated for all content

Tags: search, 2013

We have a custom search integration with SharePoint. In 2010 we relied on the SiteTitle managed property to be populated for all content items returned by search queries in order to populate a custom search results page.

Now when querying against SP 2013 it seems that this property is not always populated for all items. This makes our search results page inaccurate as we are populating filters with counts where this property is populated.

Is there anything extra that needs to be done to ensure the SiteTitle managed property is populated for all content items in the index? It is currently set to be Queryable, and Retrievable, but not Searchable (as we don't want to actually search against this value, just use it as meta-data).

Comment: Hi Tim, did you ever resolve this issue? I've been seeing similar results in our farm and I'm puzzled.